# Change Theme while app is running

Tags: android

I am working on an app and I want to have a night mode option. I have already created two themes named HoloLight and HoloDark. I can set these themes in the apps manifest and they both work fine. The problem is I can't find a way to switch between the two with code. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setTheme method in onCreate() Method like

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
```

This should be above setContentView

Comment: This still doesn't make it change. I need to make it change when a checkbox is selected.

Comment: Probably need to refresh the activity on checkBox listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme only before setcontentview. 
`setTheme(android.R.style.HoloDark);` 
so basically to change theme in app you will have to restart your activity. see [this example](http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837) for that. If you have some data to be saved, save that in instance state by using these functions in activity, 
 `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` 
`onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`